# Excel CSV with functions in any language

Tags: excel, function, csv

I have to create a CSV file to be opened by Excel for many users. 
I need to use a function in it, but the excel client users language can be diferent from one to another, so i have to write the function name "in a generic language".

=HYPERLINK(...               *(English)*
=HIPERVINCULO(...        *(Spanish)*
=ENLLAÇ(...                     *(Catalan)*

i know i have to use " to scape all the formula and an aditional " to scape the " caràcter and it worts in one computer, but when i change to another computer language it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: A `csv` file is text, whereas an `xls` or `xlsx` will store the function AFAIK. Any reason you can't use that kind of file format?

Comment: Can you use another format that the other users would open before exporting automatically to CSV? (with VBA it wouldn t be hard)

Comment: gms0ulman thanks. Reason of cost

Comment: Pierre44 thanks. i'm looking for the easy way to just add that column without touching anything else.